# What is the meaning of this exercise?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The daily quantity demanded of unleaded gasoline in a regional market can be represented as

Q=100-10p+E, where p belongs to [0,8],

and E is a random variable having a probability density given by

f(e)=0.025 I[-20,20] (e) with I is an indicator function.

Quantity demanded,Q, is measured in thousands of gallons and price,p, is measured in dollars.

If the average variable cost of supplying Q amount of unleaded gasoline is given by C(Q)=Q^(0.5)/2, define a random variable that can be used to represent **the daily profit above variable cost** from the sale of unleaded gasoline.

What is "daily profit above variable cost"? I do not know what is this, so I cannot solve this exercise. Please help me.

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t be certain, since I’m not very familiar with economic terminology, but I suspect that it’s simply $pQ-C(Q)$: $pQ$ is the amount of money obtained by selling $Q$ units at the price $p$, and $C(Q)$ is the variable cost of obtaining those $Q$ units, so the difference $pQ-C(Q)$ is the profit over and above that variable cost. (It may not be the real profit, since there may be other costs.)